# i want to show the msg from start date to end date

Tags: angular

> app.component.html

```
<div>
<label for="start">Start date:</label>
<input type="time" id="start" name="start" [(ngModel)]="start">
<label for="start">End date: </label>
<input type="time" id="end" name="end"[(ngModel)]="end">
<button type="submit" (click)="On()">submit</button>
</div>

<div> some msg </div>
```

> app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {

start;
end;

On(){
console.log('ur obj'+this.start+' '+this.end);
 }
}
```

> want to show "some msg" when start date come and disable when end date come

Comment: *ngIf="!end && start"

Comment: but doesnt work in time @Никита Середа

Comment: @НикитаСереда can u explain

Comment: add tick (setInterval) where u will increment start &/|| end